# How to set the 2 image to auto resize in Mobile view?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap3 for my website. 
The question is : 
I have 2 images in header which are left and right corner. However, when I resize the screen to mobile view, these 2 images are broken to next line.

[In large screen device is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bggas.png)

but in the small screen device...
[the 2 images are broken 2 line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDDET.png)

Image 1 applied the class "pull-left", "img-responsive"
Image 2 applied the class : "pull-right", "img-responsive"

How to solve this problem?
how to set 2 images can resize in same level line?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the line of the site you are working on. In this case it will be easy for anyone to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: show some code and better provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS file and add minimum width on the header. AFAIK, the smallest device width is 320 pixels, so try:

```
#someID of your header{
    min-width: 320px;
}
```

Don't forget to link the custom CSS file in your HTML...

I also advise you to change your menu structure. Open your menu items and place them on the upper navigation and collapse the menu when small screen detected. The examples in the bootstrap site are great!

EDIT:

Here is an example of two images, placed side by side, and staying so even when resizing page to mobile device size. In case you haven't heard about the grid system of bootstrap, make sure you read about it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <img src="../img/220px.png" class="img-responsive center-block" id="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <img src="../img/270px.png" class="img-responsive center-block" id="img2">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the custom CSS file add:

```
.container{
    min-width: 320px;
}

#img1 {
    min-height: 60px;
}

#img2 {
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. But, image1 width is 270px, image2 width is 220px. If I set to my header min-width: 490px,  this also will not resize the 2 image after I changed to mobile view. Did I something miss?

Comment: @wilsontwc, just edited my answer with working example. I checked it with two sample images of size 220x60 and 270x60 and it works when resizing to mobile screen size.